# Substitution leads me to wrong result for the integral $\int_0^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I have a question that should have been trivial to solve, but for some reason I keep messing up.  I need to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$

I initially tried to solve this with the substitution:

$$u=-\lambda x$$

This leads to the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=-\frac{u}{\lambda}\\
dx&=-\frac{du}{\lambda}
\end{aligned}$$

### My first (wrong) attempt:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx &= \lambda\int_0^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}} e^{u}\frac{-du}{\lambda}\\
& = -\int_0^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}} e^{u}du = -[e^u]_0^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}}\\
&= -[e^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}}-e^0] = 1 - e^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}} = 1 - e^x
\end{aligned}
$$

Online tools have shown that the answer is supposed to be $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ however.

### My second slightly modified attempt:

I reuse the steps from my first attempt all the way until I get:

$$-[e^u]_0^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}}$$

and now I replace the substitution first before continuing:

$$
\begin{aligned}
-[e^u]_0^{\frac{-u}{\lambda}} &= -[e^{-\lambda x}]_0^x\\
& = -[e^{-\lambda x} - e^0]\\
& = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}
\end{aligned}
$$

What sorcery is this?  I can't seem to recall a rule about substituting the variables back to the original before filling in the limits.  Otherwise, what is the point of changing the limits along with the substitution?  I must be missing something obvious here, but not obvious enough for me to notice.

### Without substitution works without a problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx &= -[e^{-\lambda x}]_0^xdx\\
& = -[e^{-\lambda x} - 1]\\
&= 1 - e^{-\lambda x}
\end{aligned}
$$

Why was my first attempt wrong?

Comment: In cases like this, where you only use the substituion for the part of evaluating the indefinite integral, I would suggest to not change the borders of integration. Just leave them as they are and plug in the values into the resubstituted anti-derivative in the end. To change the limits is only a crucial point when you are working with the integral itself without computing the value.

Comment: It is not defined. You can not have $dx$ inside if you have $x$ in one of the integral limits.

Comment: @mrtaurho. But $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \{ x = ky \} = \int_a^b f(ky) \, k \, dy$ is certainly wrong.

Comment: @md2perpe let's say $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int_{x=a}^{x=b} f(ky) k \ \mathrm dy$

Comment: +1 with @mathreadler : $(e^{-\lambda x})'=-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, so $\int_0^X \lambda e^{-\lambda x}{\rm d}x = \left[-e^{-\lambda x}\right]_0^X = 1-e^{-\lambda X}$.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the symbol for the integration parameter in the integration boundaries.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes of course. I am not talking about ignoring the fact of subsitute the limits. My typical way to denote this is to set $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\{x=ky\}=\int_{(a)}^{(b)}f(ky)k dy$ to keep it in my mind that I changed the limits. But I do not exactly evaluate the changed limits but just resubstitute before plugging the limtis in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your wrong attempt you wrote:
$$\int_0^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \ \mathrm dx = \lambda\int_0^{\color{red}{\frac{-u}{\lambda}}} e^{u}\frac{-\mathrm du}{\lambda}$$
when in fact you should have written:
$$\int_0^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \ \mathrm dx = \lambda\int_0^{\color{red}u} e^{u}\frac{-\mathrm du}{\lambda}$$

When changing the bounds, ask yourself "when $x$ = lower bound, what is $u$? when $x$ = upper bound, what is $u$?"

The answer is "when $x=0$, $u=0$; when $x=x$, $u=u$".

Comment: But it is still wrong (and confusing, see the OP) to write $\int_0^x f(x){\rm d}x$...

Comment: Well $\displaystyle \int_0^x f(x) \ \mathrm dx$ isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: For the sanity of students, it SHOULD be :-)

Comment: @KennyLau yes it is wrong. It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, for some reason that took a while to sink in and now I feel stupid because how obvious it is (as I expected it would be).  I shouldn't have written the upper bound in terms of *x=...*, but keep it in the form of *u=...*.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One mistake at the start with the substitution $u=-\lambda x$ you should get $$dx = -\frac{du}{\lambda} $$
but for some reason you get 
$$dx = -\frac{du}{x}$$

If you keep going from that spot (and change integral limit to for example $X$ as proposed by Nicolas Francois) you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  It was supposed to be lambda, but I made a typing mistake with my OP.  I edited it.